# Laravel belongs returns none

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a `user model`, which can have many reports, and a report model obviously belonging to a user, whenever one is created.

However when I use return `$this->belongsTo('App\User')` on the `report model` No user is returned even when I have the correct `user_id` on the report, and correct id on the user table.

User

```
protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', 'password',
];

public function reports()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Report');
}
```

Report

```
protected $fillable = [
    'user_id', 'title', 'detail',
];

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id');
}
```

Comment: add your model code

Comment: I've added codes of the models. Thank you for your time.

Comment: How you are using it where you are saying that it is returning null?

Comment: I am testing it by getting the first report, and using $report->user(), which doesn't return any user. Note that $report is actually a valid report model with existing values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it simply by using `$report->user`, instead of calling it like a function via `$report->user()`